# Can't find any way to get POST requests working Reddit API - 403 Error

Tags: javascript, post, axios, postman, reddit

I'm trying to build a reddit-like app on react native, so i'm using axios to fetch requests to Reddit Api and I can't seem to be able to fetch any POST requests, I've tried everything I can, I'm trying to subscribe to a subreddit, here is my request :

```
subscribe: async function subscribe(action, sub, modhash) {
       try {
    const token = await this.getAccessToken();
    console.log('token: ' + token)
    let Headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Modhash': modhash}
    let Params =  {'action': action, 'sr_name': sub}
    let Body = {'api_type': "json", "extension": "json"}
    await axios.post('https://oauth.reddit.com/api/subscribe', Headers, Params, Body)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('sub: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
      console.log("Subbed to " + sub)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw 'Could not sub: ' + error
  }
},
```

Here is the Catch result:

```
"Could not sub: Error: Request failed with status code 403"
```

here is the official api about subscribe : https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#POST_api_subscribe

`action` = `"sub"` and `sr` = `"t5_2qh03"` and I tried `sr_name` and `sr` but none seems to work, I'm sure the token is valid since it works with other GET requets I can't find what I did wrong here. Do you guys have any idea on what I'm missing ?

Edit: I've tried the same request with postman and the request actually worked, i did sub to a subreddit, but the same exact request is not working with axios, does my request is okay ?

Comment: 403 is forbidden. You dont have access to the ressource you are trying to use.

Comment: I can't understand why, my token is ok, i've checked it many times, and the same token lets me access other api routes, like subreddits data etc etc

Comment: An issued token has a scope. Only because you have a token doesnt mean you have access to everything. Make sure, that your token scope is valid for the action you are trying to use and that what you are trying to do is matching the documentation precisely.

Comment: Ok i'm gonna check and edit the scopes

Comment: So i've added every scopes but it's still the same, 403 error

Comment: Are you sure that your headers and body are sent with the request? Because the `axios.post` config param looks odd.

Comment: I'll try to edit them

Comment: I've Edited it, but still get the same error, i've put everything in vars like i saw on other axios post requests, Is it okay this way ? (I edited the original post)

Answer (score 1):

To me, your code is alright.

However, the Reddit API is such a *clusterfuck*, that peoples are not much using it.

They are using [pupeeter](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) and similar.

For your problem, it all depends of the subreddit, some (many) are not allowing to POST by API at all, of course without warning, or with totally unclear HTTP error codes It just doesn't work.

There is also situations where it works, but only sometimes, or only the first time, or only from an IP of a given allowed country.

They are also widely using black/grey/white listing, shadow banning, and rate limiting. But no notices are ever given. The definition of a *clusterfuck*.

Comment: Man, that's very fucked, I love the concept of API, but this, So, Using the request via Postman works but not on axios, i'm gonna try with other subs, until now I was trying with "gaming" sub, Thanks for the advices, do you by chance have any idea on what's wrong or should I just give up on this ? thanks again

Comment: Personally I gave up using the API. Yes the «gaming»© sub is large and likely widely controlled, by Humans and by scripts (it involves big $$$). Try your tools on another sub (those where you can see bots posting messages), and even try to create one sub yourself. You will see, posting on your own sub will works. If you go for pupeeter, make sure to use the «old reddit», as the rebranding is really adding an extra level of complexity.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just tried on many subs like bmw, nintendo, france, etc etc, but none of them worked, i'm going to do what you said, if nothing works, go to sleep ah ah, thank you

Comment: Same error on SubredditSimulator, which seems to be THE bot friendly subreddit, and still got 403, maybe Reddit doesn't like baguette users :'(. Thanks you all for your help, i'm going to sleep

Comment: Yeah, maybe ;) API are great in general, but this one in particular is not a good one to learn stuffs quickly, it's just insane.

Comment: Sadly I was forced to use it for my school project :( But I will make a tons of other things with API now, i can't unthink of various ways to do it ! :)

Comment: Please report if you manage to succeed POSTing on a minor sub, or your own. For peoples later-on. Don't hesitate to publish an answer with your conclusions. It's always good to write stuff down. Bonne journée poto.

Comment: I have an appointment for the end project with the project manager and we will see what he say's about it, et merci toi aussi bro :)